# How to estimate a function by a table?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I would like to estimate some benchmark score function, as it is based only on core and memory frequency values. In my particular example: Given a 2D table, filled with performance measurements of some GPU algorithm. Each column is for each measured GPU core frequency, each row is for memory frequency. In each crossing there is benchmark value.

It is a 2D matrix, but it is also can be viewed as a kind of linear function of 2 variables: bench_score(fCore,fMem) Assuming there is no non-linearities, how can i estimate this function bench_score() from measurements in 2D table

I mean, i need to estimate benchark result for arbitary pair of frequencies, based on measurements. I need hints, to provide function form and methods of finding its coeffitients from table.

PS: Chart data could help to imagine this surface.
[image]

Comment: PPS. This graph is build using linear interpolation in google charts. Lerp`ing between cells is not that i want, for example how can i find value for bench_score(1160,2060)? Linear interpolation will not help, i need a complete function of 2 arguments. It must be some simple function, maybe someone just knows.

Comment: I'd use 2d linear interpolation, your data are quite smooth so it will work nicely. If you don't like it your drawing suggests an interpolating function like $bs=((kf_{core}-l)^{-1}+(mf_{member}+n)^{-1})^{-1}$. You'll need to find the values for $k,l,m,n$ that give you the best interpolation for the data.

Comment: @N74 could you provide form, at least for me to start from? like "f(x) = a*x^2 + b*x + c" ?   here is function bench_score(fCore,fMem) = ???

Comment: I just did it... my $bs$ function depends on $f_{core}, f_{mem}$  as soon as you find the right parameters.

Comment: @N74 ah thanks, i got you!